# How to validate exact 9 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I want to validate nine digit account number so i use the following validator :

```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_manual" ErrorMessage="Wrong account number" ValidationExpression="^\\d{9}$" ValidationGroup="M1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

---

Using : `^\\d{9}$`

but i always get `wrong account number` even with the exact nine numbers like :

```
000067543
900765432
098675432
```

Comment: what do you get in response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't escape `\d`:

```
^\d{9}$
```

Comment: And that's cause in regex `\d` means digits and you are saying exact 9 digints. You can as well write this as `^[0-9]{9}$`